# Solve the following equation $x'(t)+y'(t)=\frac{2}{5}y(t)-\frac{3}{5}x(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following equation
$$x'(t)+y'(t)=\frac{2}{5}y(t)-\frac{3}{5}x(t)\, .$$
I think that it is possible to write
$$x'(t)=-\frac{3}{5}x(t)\, ,\ y'(t)=\frac{2}{5}y(t)$$
separately but I don't know why.

I would appreciate some help with this problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This equation is undeterminate. You can take an arbitrary function $x(t)$, plug it in the equation and solve for $y(t)$.

Comment: "I think that it is possible to write..." Without further information, it is not. Please indicate your source for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x'(t)+y'(t)=\frac{2}{5}y(t)-\frac{3}{5}x(t)$$
$$x'+\frac{3}{5}x+y'-\frac{2}{5}y=0$$
$$e^{-\dfrac35t}\left(e^{\dfrac35t}x'+\frac{3}{5}e^{\dfrac35t}x\right)+e^{\dfrac25t}\left(e^{-\dfrac25t}y'-\frac{2}{5}e^{-\dfrac25t}y\right)=0$$
$$\left(e^{\dfrac35t}x\right)'+e^t\left(e^{-\dfrac25t}y\right)'=0$$
$$\left(e^{-\dfrac25t}y\right)'=e^{-t}\left(e^{\dfrac35t}x\right)'$$
After simplification and intergation by oarts we have
$$y=x+e^{\frac25t}\int xe^{-\frac25t}dt+Ce^{\frac25t}$$

Comment: for instance with $x=t$ you find $$y=-\frac32t-\frac{25}{4}+Ce^{\frac25t}$$